# I get "Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ip:4000" when I try to connect to the server built in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, centos, firewall

I have centos 6 running nodejs 10,
and i have this scaffold code to test my application server but still giving Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ip:4000

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3432
const https = require('https');
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

When i try to put the url in the browser it says This site can’t be reached.
I like server is not running but it is running.

Comment: well, your server is listening on port 3432, so you won't be able to contact it at port 4000

Comment: Yes sorry, Was a port error when I wrote. The port is the same . The error maybe is for firewall

Answer (score 0):

The error was that server administrator dont enable the port for me

Comment: he said he had opened the port